# TensorBoard does not show scalars

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am playing TensorBoard and cannot make a simple example work. The computation is simply adding two constants.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.constant(1, name = "const1")
b = tf.constant(10, name = "const2")
c = a + b

asum = tf.summary.scalar("g1" , a)
bsum = tf.summary.scalar("g2",  b)
csum = tf.summary.scalar("gsum", c)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()


train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.\logs',sess.graph)

summary, _ = sess.run([merged, c])

train_writer.add_summary(summary, 0)
```

Then I compiled it first:

```
>python filename.py
```

everything looks good.

Then :

```
>tensorboard --logdir=".\logs" --inspect
```

The weird thing occurred: there were no scalars!

```
Found event files in:
.\logs

These tags are in .\logs:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars -
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for .\logs:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars -
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================
```

Version of TensorFlow is: 1.2.1

Python version: 3.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileWriter` object buffers the event it collects and then, once the buffer is full, write them on the disk.
A single call of the `FileWriter` object isn't enough the fill the buffer, thus you to force the `FileWriter` to flush the buffer and write the content on the disk. To do that, just call `.close()` after the `add_summary` operation.

```
train_writer.add_summary(summary, 0)
train_writer.close()
```

This will close the `train_writer` object and you can't use it anymore.

If you, instead, want to just flush the buffer without closing the file, you can use the `.flush()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the sess.run worked for me when I faced the exact same issue.

```
_, summary = sess.run([c, merged])
```